# Fire an event when a component is loaded(Opened)

Tags: angular

I want to trigger an event when a corresponding event is opened. Let me explain the scenario.

This is my component selector

```
<app-sadad class="knet-div" [payMethod]="'knet'"></app-sadad>
```

which is placed inside another component html, Inside the app-sadad component, I have used reactive form, if payMethod = Knet, I have to validators.required to particular formControl(olpid).

```
this.sadadForm = new FormGroup({
          'olpid': new FormControl(''),
          'firstName': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      });
```

I have tried ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit which didn`t get fired on form load, it fires on application load. Kindly tell me the event which gets fired on particular form load.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check onInit if the value for payMethod === 'knet', then compose Validators including required. Otherwise leave it null.

Validators.compose returns a ValidationFn. You can assign that to the form control.

```
@Input() payMethod;
validatorsComposition = null;

ngOnInit(){
  if(this.payMethod === 'knet'){
    this.validatorsComposition = Validators.compose([Validators.required]);
  } 

  this.sadadForm = new FormGroup({
      'olpid': new FormControl('', this.validatorsComposition),
      'firstName': new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.